# Отправка email-письма с картинкой

Tags: php, email, outlook

Надо отправить сообщение с изображением: Отобразить и иллюстрацию в письме и повесить на нее html map.

Функция для отправки:

```
function SendMyMail($to,$from,$subject,$message,$boundary,$filename){
    $headers = "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"";
    $body = "--" . $boundary . "\n";
    $body .= "Content-type: text/html; charset='utf-8'\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printablenn";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n\n";
    $body .= $message."\n";
    $body .= "--$boundary\n";
    $file = fopen($filename, "r"); //Открываем файл
    $text = fread($file, filesize($filename)); //Считываем весь файл
    fclose($file); //Закрываем файл
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n\n";
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($text))."\n";
    $body .= "--".$boundary ."--\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); //Отправляем письмо
}
```

html письма:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
    <META content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
    <MAP name=FPMap0>
    <AREA href="site.com/" shape="rect" coords="112, 73, 668, 132">
    </MAP>
<BODY>
    <P align=center>
        <IMG border=0 src="сюда надо вставить картинку"  width=800 height=1964 useMap=#FPMap0>
    </P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Как мне в `img` сослаться на картинку?

Пробовал просто подставить путь к картинке в интернете, но Outlook её не отображает.

Answer (score 3):

мне вот [это](http://vk-book.ru/otpravka-pisem-s-kartinkami-na-php/) помогло.

```
// картинки
$attach = array(
    'http://vk-book.ru/img/scroll_mouse.jpg',
    'http://vk-book.ru/img/ugly.png'
);
// чтобы отображалась картинка и ее не было в аттаче
// путь к картинке задается через CID: - Content-ID
// тестовый текст
$text = '
    <div style="width: 700px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <h1>тело письма с картинкой</h1>
        <h2>Блок по центру</h2>
        <p>
            <img style="float: left; margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;" src="cid:scroll_mouse.jpg" width="128" height="128" />
            Какой-то текст вокруг картинки. Какой-то текст вокруг картинки. Какой-то текст вокруг картинки. Какой-то текст вокруг картинки.
            <br/>
            <img style="float: left; margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;" src="cid:ugly.png" width="128" height="128" />
            Какой-то текст вокруг картинки. Какой-то текст вокруг картинки. Какой-то текст вокруг картинки. Какой-то текст вокруг картинки.
        </p>
    </div>
';

$from = "test@test.com";
$to = "zhenikipatov@yandex.ru";
$subject = "Тема письма";

// Заголовки письма === >>>
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
//$headers .= "To: $to\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject: $subject\r\n";
$headers .= "Date: " . date("r") . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: zm php script\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\r\n";
$baseboundary = "------------" . strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
$headers .= "  boundary=\"$baseboundary\"\r\n";
// <<< ====================

// Тело письма === >>>
$message  =  "--$baseboundary\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/plain;\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--$baseboundary\r\n";
$newboundary = "------------" . strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
$message .= "Content-Type: multipart/related;\r\n";
$message .= "  boundary=\"$newboundary\"\r\n\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--$newboundary\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$message .= $text . "\r\n\r\n";
// <<< ==============

// прикрепляем файлы ===>>>
foreach($attach as $filename){
    $mimeType='image/png';
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($filename,true);
    $filename=basename($filename);
    $message.="--$newboundary\r\n";
    $message.="Content-Type: $mimeType;\r\n";
    $message.=" name=\"$filename\"\r\n";
    $message.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message.="Content-ID: <$filename>\r\n";
    $message.="Content-Disposition: inline;\r\n";
    $message.=" filename=\"$filename\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message.=chunk_split(base64_encode($fileContent));
}
// <<< ====================

// заканчиваем тело письма, дописываем разделители
$message.="--$newboundary--\r\n\r\n";
$message.="--$baseboundary--\r\n";

// отправка письма
$result = mail($to, $subject, $message , $headers);
var_dump($result);
```

Вставляет картинки как вложения и отправляет письмо. Все картинки, вставленные в письме при помощи src="cid:имяфайла.тип" не показываются как вложения.

Также есть пример в книге PHP5 in practice, в главе 16.1 подробно описана отправка емэйлов, в том числе и вставка картинок в текст (Листинг 16.1.4).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/69701)

Comment: Исправил ответ, добавил код и небольшое пояснение.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем php-коде Вы прикрепляете картинку как аттач, что по идее ни к чему.
Рассыльщики всяческих рекламных бюллетеней и т.п. формируют html-код письма, таким образом, что все картинки тянутся с их серверов - надо смотреть в эту сторону.
В свою очередь большинство почтовых клиентов по умолчанию не подгружают картинки в целях безопасности, в отличие от большинства веб-интерфейсов (а'ля [mail.ru](http://mail.ru), [yandex.ru](http://yandex.ru), ...).

Comment: >> Как мне в IMG соослатся на картинку??? Пробывал подставить просто путь к картинке в нете, но Аутлук ее не отображает...

угу это я уже понял, но факт в том что щас рассылка производится с подкрипленымы картинками и они отображаются)

так вот мне интересно как это зделать?

Comment: надо в голову вставить еще 1 пункт Content-ID: $id  
и когда хочешь вывести картинку в адрес вписуеш "cid:$id"

Answer (score 0):

Есть один простой метод, без всяких аттачей) Если картинка находится на вашем сервере то можно просто прописать линк для нее и она подтянется c вашего сервера.

```
<IMG border=0 src="http://site.com/img/image.jpg"  width=800 height=1964 useMap=#FPMap0>
```

Comment: Вы вообще читали вопрос???

Answer (score 0):

Преобразуешь картинку в base64 и вставляешь как data-uri.