# Отправка письма с картинками в теле письма, а не в приложении

Tags: php, email

Приветствую всех второй раз

```
$to  = "***@ya.ru" ;
$subject = "theme"; 
$message = ' 
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
смотрите, там ниже картинка! не приложение к письму, а картинка!
<img src="img/image.jpg">
</body> 
</html>
'; 
$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: Текст 4 <no-reply@my-site.ru>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Bcc: no-reply@my-site.ru\r\n"; 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

В интернете полно примеров как прикрепить к письму файл, в.т.ч. картинку. А как можно в текст письма вставить в картинку?

В гугле был, и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/126906/php-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-email-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9), и еще пробовал так писать:

```
<img src="cid:img/image.jpg">
```

вообще ничего не помогло. Может кто указать как вставить картинку в письмо?

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email

Что бы вставить картинку в текст, ее все-равно необходимо прикрепить к письму, и в src-атрибуте указать ее Content-ID.

Можно еще попробовать указать абсолютный путь к картинке (http://path.to/image.jpg. Но почтовые клиенты могут блокировать такие изображения.

Еще на stackoverflow предлагают в src засовывать всю картинку в base64.

Comment: @Artem Ryzhov, эту ссылку гугл тоже выдает. вот мне бы рабочий пример, как это дело применять

и пример на stackoverflow у меня не сработал 8-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В книге [PHP 5 in Practice](http://fumblog.um.ac.ir/gallery/187/PHP%205%20in%20Practice.pdf) есть пример в разделе *Listing 16.1.4. Using Embedded Images in HTML Email*.

Comment: Ну вот же оно! То самое! Спасибо!

Comment: Ссылка не работает

Comment: @sercxjo исправил